# How can I cross-reference 2 models in Mongoose by ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm sure this question has been answered but I'm not sure if I'm wording this correctly in my searches.

Let's say I have 2 models: project, and user

```
projectSchema = {
  project_name: String,
  users: [user_id]
}
userSchema = {
  email: String,
  projects: [project_id]
}
```

When a user attempts to create a new project, I want to check to see if that User.projects already includes a project with the name they are attempting to create, to avoid duplicates.  Since the User.projects array only contains the id's of the projects, I'm having trouble. I'm sure a method exists in Mongoose but I'm having difficulty finding a simple way to do this without first generating an array of all the user's project_id's and querying every one for a matching name.

I've seen a lot of mention of something that would look roughly like:

```
User.find({}).populate('projects').exec();
```

Yet I can't create a working implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution.  While it certainly isn't elegant, it is the best I can do.  For anyone with the same question, here is what I did:

```
const getTakenName = async () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      Project.find({name: project.name})
      .populate('users')
      .exec((err, project) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        for (let i in project) {
          let sameName = project[i];
          if (sameName.users.find(user => {
            return user.user_id == req.user.id;
          })) {
            return resolve(true);
          } 
        }
        resolve(false);
      })
  })
  }

 let takenName = await getTakenName();
```

This finds all Projects with a given name, then populates all User collections which are in the users array for that Project by their ID.  From there it iterates through all matched Projects, and searches all its Users for an ID that matches the current User's.  If one is found, the enveloping promise resolves as true.  Otherwise, it resolves as false.